# Passing json data list to HttpPost controller in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, postman

I have a model:

```
public class NotificationsDeliveryTypesIds
{
  public int NotificationGroupId { get; set; }
  public int DeliveryTypeId { get; set; }
  public int UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoiceId { get; set; }
  public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

In my `HomeController` I have:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public void SaveNotifications(List<NotificationsDeliveryTypesIds> selectedNotificationDeliveryTypesIds)
{
}
```

I put a debugger in my `SaveNBotifications` method, and I'm trying to call it from **Postman**, but I got:

> 400 error - bad request.

I am trying to pass in the body:

```
[{
"NotificationGroupId": 1,
"DeliveryTypeId": 2,
"UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoiceId": 3,
"Selected":true
}]
```

When I put `asp-controller` and `asp-home`, it hits debugger. And I can see in my chrome debugger data like:

```
selectedDeliveryTypes: 1,1,0
selectedDeliveryTypes: 3,2,271
selectedDeliveryTypes: 4,2,272
selectedDeliveryTypes: 4,1,273
selectedDeliveryTypes: 5,2,0
```

I want to be able to hit breakpoint from my Postman.

Comment: Do you have `ApiControllerAttribute` on your controller? If not, then add it, or add `[FromBody]` to action parameter  like `[FromBody]List<NotificationsDeliveryTypesIds> selectedNotificationDeliveryTypesIds`

Comment: What's the name of your controller and does it have attributes above it? Also, are you testing it on localhost?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk it isnt the matter, because, I removed that list as param and add just dummy input `(int? id = null)` and still nothing. If my Body is set to none in postmen, because of the predefined null value for int? id it needs to bind it ?

Comment: @G.Dimov yes, Im testing it in localhost:44300. also each method has annotations, this method that has[HttpPost] as well as [HttpAnonymous], my controller name is HomeController

Comment: Show us screen of potman

Comment: Have you tried the following in postman: The URL is: http://localhost:44300/Home , the request type is `POST`, then you click on `Body` -> select raw -> from the dropdown select JSON -> paste your JSON and then hit Send. Does this work? If not change the URL to http://localhost:44300 and try again. Not sure if you have any Route attributes above yout controller. Don't forget the http:// in the beginning

Comment: @G.Dimov not, this will not mwork, because I need specific method in my controller, such as SaveNotifications

Comment: I also added Test method [HttpGet] and it worked! But when I tryu to call [HtpPost], I cant!

Comment: Then add the following above your method `[Route("/SaveNotifications")]` and then hit http://localhost:44300/Home/SaveNotifications

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I didnt?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk you obviously mixed me up with someone elese..

Answer (score 0):

Modify your controller action by decorating the parameter with the `[FromBody]` attribute.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public void SaveNotifications([FromBody] List<NotificationsDeliveryTypesIds> selectedNotificationDeliveryTypesIds)
{
}
```

Comment: that isnt a problem, because I cant see the method from postman

Comment: Then if this is your only POST action on your Home controller, you should try invoking simply by performing a POST on http://[host:port]/Home.
If you include more than one action you need to specify a route for each post action, e.g. ```[HttpPost("<some route>")]```

Answer (score -1):

the problem was with AUthenticationCookie